# onClick not working in fragment. (using imageview as a button)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I want to implement onclick in my fragment to change fragment.

Here is this function:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    imageView9 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    imageView9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Create new fragment and transaction
            Fragment newFragment = new FragEditProfile();
            // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }

    });
```

It's 'clicking' cause I hear the typical button sound. But i'm getting this error when clicks:

```
ssl=0xaf840c00 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xa17d2280 arg=0x0
ssl=0xaf840c00 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

Here is my main_activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarInner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#212"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_app_bar_layout">




            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout="@layout/top_points_bar" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:paddingStart="16dp"
                app:tabPaddingStart="16dp"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="16dp"
                app:tabMinWidth="96dp"
                app:tabGravity="center" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/md_brown_100"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        android:textColor="@color/okurwa"
        app:theme="@style/MyTabStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/MyTabTextStyle"
        android:clipToPadding="false">





        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_wallet_id"
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_total_credits"
            android:layout_width="182dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"/>



        <!--<FrameLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom"-->
        <!--android:background="@color/md_white_1000"-->
        <!--android:elevation="4dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="-96dp">-->

        <!--<Button android:id="@+id/navigation_button_footer"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:text=""-->
        <!--android:textSize="13sp"-->
        <!--android:textColor="@color/md_grey_800"-->
        <!--android:lines="3"-->
        <!--android:gravity="center"-->
        <!--style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"-->
        <!--android:paddingTop="20dp"-->
        <!--android:paddingLeft="20dp"-->
        <!--android:paddingRight="20dp"-->
        <!--android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>-->

        <!--</FrameLayout>-->

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_connection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actmain_margintop"
        android:background="#3c3c3c"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_error"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/error_no_internet"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twentyfive" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_dialog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/error_no_internet"
                android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/twentyfive" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please help me guys! I see this error first time. I don't know why I'm getting this error and why it's not working. Thanks Stack's Community!

## EDIT

This is full code of this fragment:

```
/**
 * Created by otsma on 12.12.2016.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.commonutility.PreferenceConnector;
import com.justfashion.R;

import java.util.Random;



public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
    final Random rnd = new Random();


    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private static TextView creditWallet;

    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
    private TextView firstName, textView13,textView14,textView15,textView16,textView17,textView18;
    private Animation animShake, wbijam, load1, load2, load3, load4, load5, load6, wbijam1, wbijam2, wbijam3, wbijam4, wbijam5;
    private ImageView img, imageView9,imageView19,imageView4,imageView5,imageView6,imageView7,imageView8;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static void onUpdateView(Context aiContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (aiContext != null && creditWallet != null)
            creditWallet.setText(PreferenceConnector.readInteger(aiContext, PreferenceConnector.WALLETPOINTS, 0) + "");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


        imageView9 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        imageView9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Create new fragment and transaction
                Fragment newFragment = new FragEditProfile();
                // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();

            }

        });




    


        img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
        imageView4 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageView5 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imageView6 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imageView7 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        imageView8 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView8);

        firstName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.imie);


        textView13 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        textView14 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        textView15 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView16);
        textView16 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView17);
        textView17 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        textView18 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView19);

        final Animation wbijam = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView13.startAnimation(wbijam);
        final Animation wbijam1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView14.startAnimation(wbijam1);
        final Animation wbijam2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView15.startAnimation(wbijam2);
        final Animation wbijam3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView16.startAnimation(wbijam3);
        final Animation wbijam4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView17.startAnimation(wbijam4);
        final Animation wbijam5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.wbijam);
        textView18.startAnimation(wbijam5);






        final Animation animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shak);
        img.startAnimation(animShake);



        final Animation load2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load2);
        imageView4.startAnimation(load2);
        final Animation load3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load3);
        imageView5.startAnimation(load3);
        final Animation load4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load4);
        imageView6.startAnimation(load4);
        final Animation load5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load5);
        imageView7.startAnimation(load5);
        final Animation load6 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.load6);
        imageView8.startAnimation(load6);


        firstName.setText("Hey,"+" " +PreferenceConnector.readString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), PreferenceConnector.FIRST_NAME, ""));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
//  return view;
//  ^^^^  error remove it
        Resources res = getResources();

        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);

        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(q);


            // I have 3 images named img_0 to img_2, so...
        final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(9);
        img.setImageDrawable
                (
                        getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
                                getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                ));
        return view;
        // ^^^ move it here
    }

        // I have 3 images named img_0 to img_2, so...



    protected final static int getResourceID
            (final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx) {
        final int ResourceID =
                ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
                        ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
        if (ResourceID == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                    (
                            "No resource string found with name " + resName
                    );
        } else {
            return ResourceID;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: why are you calling `super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);` in `onCreateView()`?

Comment: don't forget to ,       retun view;

Comment: @BLin but where? Can You tell me?

Comment: // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }

    });    // after this

Answer (score 2):

remove super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
return your view

Comment: Where to put return view?

Comment: like this    
   
        ` @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dua, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        def_font_size = loadFontinfo();
        fetchPrefValue();
        setData(view, def_font_size);
        return view;
    }`

Answer (score 2):

please return the view

```
retun view;
```

if the problem still persists

> To Make Sure whether the problem is with  Onclick or not,  comment
>   Everything inside the onclick method and put a Toast inside it.  so, i
>   think we could get a clear picture about the problem..

Comment: Where to put return view?

Comment: just before closing onCreateView

Comment: nope, check the full code, I've got a return view below.

Comment: why do yo use the below code

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

comment these lines . and run the code. give it a try

Answer (score 1):

try this !!

replace the following line:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

to this:

```
android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Also don't forget to `return view;`

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    imageView9 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    imageView9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Create new fragment and transaction
            Fragment newFragment = new FragEditProfile();
            // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }

    });

return view;
}
```

your fragment and fragment manager should be of same type.so either import

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

OR

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

java file

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


    imageView9 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    imageView9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Create new fragment and transaction
            Fragment newFragment = new FragEditProfile();

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                     .beginTransaction()
                     .replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
                     .addToBackStack(null)
                     .commit();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();

        }

    });


// your other contents.....



return view;
}
```

Comment: When I replace, i'm getting error in (R.id.content_frame, newFragment); (new fragment)

Comment: what error is showing, alt+Enter to get the suggestions,

Comment: your fragment and fragment manager should be of same type.so either use 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;     OR     import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

Comment: check the the updated first post with full fragment code! I've got return view but at the bottom, cause i've got more functions there. Please help

Comment: Now.Whats your problem ?? Is there any errors ?? Is it working or not ??

Comment: No, not working. The same. When I add return view like u said, the below code got error

Answer (score 0):

You better implement Interface for click event  like this

```
public class fragment_test extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_zoom_in:
//                .....
            break;

    }
    return true;

     }
   }
 }
```